# Bootstrap datetimepicker not functioning, no console errors - conflicting script?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, opencart2.x, bootstrap-datetimepicker

`http://www.pierceresults.com/pierce-results-seminars/PRS-Level-1-October-2015-Marietta-GA`

Using OpenCart, and added a time field for registrants to pick an appointment time.  The time, date, and datetime option types are failing to load the datepicker appropriately.  Oddly, the same inputs work perfectly on pages in the administration section.  I've diffed the markup, checked the libraries, and diffed the scripts.  The only differences I can find are IDs and values, etc.: Not any differences that should break the functionality.

There are no errors in the console, and when I set breakpoints in Chrome, the script appears to execute.

Could someone help with this issue?  Of course I'd just like the darned thing to work, but if the answer included some techniques for troubleshooting issues like this, I'd really appreciate it.

I spend about the same amount of time writing code and trying to figure out these infuriating non-obvious problems.  It's even worse when the markup isn't mine.  Thank you for your time.

Edit: Initialization script included for convenience.

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false
});

$('.time').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false
});

$('.datetime').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: true,
    pickTime: true
});
```

Example code from the documentation, no options:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

<strike>Some screenshots that show my code in place, still not working after trying suggested changes, and curiously, that the timepicker exists, but still won't display (Chrome)</strike>

[Div was given an ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFIWN.png)

[Initialized in Script...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxlwM.png)

[Still no love...][3]

`[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OWQI.png`

After trying all of the solutions offered in the answers below, I tried resetting the page to it's default configuration (no added scripts, etc.) and I found that a script I wrote, when present, is keeping the timepicker from displaying. I can confirm that initializing the datetimepicker using a class on the container div works as expected when the following script is not present. Is this a collision?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var originalPrice = $('.list-unstyled h2').text();//get the base price without any options selected.

var currencySymbol = originalPrice.match(/[\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]/g);//Find the currency symbol being used, put it into a variable
var currencyPosition = originalPrice.indexOf(currencySymbol);//Set the position of the currency symbol in a variable

if (currencyPosition == 0) {//If the currency symbol precedes the price..
    var originalValue = parseFloat(originalPrice.substring(1));//cut it off of the front of the price
} else {//otherwise..
    var originalValue = parseFloat(originalPrice.substring(0, currencyPosition));//cut if off of the end of the price.  This doesn't account for 2 character currency symbols.
}
optionObject = new Object();//Create a new object to store all the relevant option data in.

$('select[name^="option"] option, input[name^="option"]').each(function(index, value) {//iterate through all the options and input their data into the object.
    if($(this).text()) {

        if($(this).text().match(/(-)\$/g)){
            var negative = "-"
        } else {
            var negative = false;   
        }

        if(negative) {

            optionPrice = parseFloat(negative + $(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));

            optionObject[$(this).val()] = optionPrice; //Storing the price, with an optional negative symbol (if present)
        } else {
            optionObject[$(this).val()] = parseFloat($(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
        }

        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, ''));//remove pricing from option text
    } else {

        if($(this).text().match(/(-)\$/g)){
            var negative = "-"
        } else {
            var negative = false;   
        }

        if(negative) {
            optionPrice = parseFloat(negative + $(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
            optionObject[$(this).val()] = optionPrice;//Storing the price, with an optional negative symbol (if present)
        } else {
            optionObject[$(this).val()] = parseFloat($(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
        }

        optionObject[$(this).val()] = parseFloat($(this).parent().text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
        var children = $(this).parent().children();
        $(this).parent().text($(this).parent().text().replace(/(\([^)]+\))/g, '')).prepend(children);//remove pricing from option text
    }   
});

$('select[name^="option"], input[name^="option"]').change(function() {
    var inputSum = 0;

    $('select[name^="option"] option:selected, input[name^="option"]:checked').each(function(index, value) {
        if(!isNaN(optionObject[($(this).val())])){
            inputSum = inputSum + optionObject[($(this).val())];
        }
    });

    var finalValue = (originalValue + inputSum);

    if(currencyPosition === 0) {
        $('.list-unstyled h2').replaceWith('<h2>' + currencySymbol + finalValue + '</h2>');
    } else {
        $('.list-unstyled h2').replaceWith('<h2>' + finalValue + currencySymbol + '</h2>');
    }

    //Show/Hide dependent options.  The rest of the code is in the custom_option_choices-HOGAN.xml file
    switch (this.value) {   

        case '43': // Student Registration
        case '44': // Student Pre-Registration
            hideDependents('43');
            showDependents('43');
            break;

        case '45': // Standard Registration
        case '46': // Standard Pre-Registration
            showDependents('45');
            hideDependents('45');
            break;
    }
});
$('#input-option239 option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('select[id="input-option239"]').trigger('change');
});
```

I've narrowed the problem down further: commenting out the following portion of the above script also fixes the issue.

```
$('select[name^="option"] option, input[name^="option"]').each(function(index, value) {//iterate through all the options and input their data into the object.
    if($(this).text()) {        
        if($(this).text().match(/(-)\$/g)){
            var negative = "-"
        } else {
            var negative = false;   
        }

        if(negative) {
            optionPrice = parseFloat(negative + $(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));

            optionObject[$(this).val()] = optionPrice; //Storing the price, with an optional negative symbol (if present)
        } else {
            optionObject[$(this).val()] = parseFloat($(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
        }

        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\(([^)]+)\)/g, ''));//remove pricing from option text
    } else {

        if($(this).text().match(/(-)\$/g)){
            var negative = "-"
        } else {
            var negative = false;   
        }

        if(negative) {
            optionPrice = parseFloat(negative + $(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
            optionObject[$(this).val()] = optionPrice;//Storing the price, with an optional negative symbol (if present)
        } else {
            optionObject[$(this).val()] = parseFloat($(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
        }

        optionObject[$(this).val()] = parseFloat($(this).parent().text().match(/(\d+\.\d+)/g));
        var children = $(this).parent().children();
        $(this).parent().text($(this).parent().text().replace(/(\([^)]+\))/g, '')).prepend(children);//remove pricing from option text
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your `.datetime` element is a `div`.. It should be `input` where you need to initialize `datepicker`?

So just add `.datetime` class to `input` and initialize it as below:

```
$('input.datetime').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: true,
    pickTime: true
});
```

Check the below screenshot which I took after executing above step in `console`

[image: Here is the proof]

---

**Update**

So I just added an `id` to your `div` and as per your lookup in documentation, they have assigned it to `id` for a `div`. Check the below images:

**DOM**

[image: Added Id]

**Console**

[image: After executing in console]

> So, I think you should initialize it on `id` for `div` instead of
>   `class`

Comment: According to the documentation (I edited the question to include it) my markup is correct...  I'll do anything to be able to move on.  The odd thing is that the markup on the site works fine in a different context (the administration panel, the code is exactly the same).

Comment: According to the documentation they have initialized it on `id`- `#datetimepicker1`.. Can you try once the same?

Comment: Yes, I set the id to `timepicker252` and tried to initialize it.  I also tried your method, and neither are displaying.

Comment: Did your try hitting that `calendar` icon?

Comment: Answering this question to close it.  Thank you for your time and effort, but it turns out the problem isn't actually with the datetimepicker.

Comment: @JeffH.. if you have found it to be different problem and solved it in your way then definitely you can post it and mark it as answer so that others get useful info from this post.. Anyways.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: You solved the stated problem, I was just wrong about what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

*Preferred Time for Evaluation (Friday 10:00-2:00):*

```
<div class="input-group datetime">
     <input type="text" name="option[252]" value="" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" id="input-option252" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>     </button>
   </span>  
 </div>
```

And your js is :

```
$('.datetime').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: true,
    pickTime: true
});
```

I think it should be `$('.datetime input').datetimepicker({`

Comment: I'll try that, but for reference, the markup and script are exactly the same in the administration panel, but it works over there.  Be right back with feedback.